# Condição if/else para marcar/desmarcar checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Gostaria de saber como seria uma condição para desmarcar todos meus `ckeckbox`.

```
function marcarDesmarcarTodos() {
    for (i = 0; i <= 500; i++) {
        document.getElementById('seleciona_ativarDesativar_'+i).checked = true;
    }
}
```

Tentei da seguinte maneira, mas não deu certo.

```
function marcarDesmarcarTodos() {
    for (i = 0; i <= 500; i++) {
        if (document.getElementById('seleciona_ativarDesativar_'+i) != 'checked') {
            document.getElementById('seleciona_ativarDesativar_'+i).checked = true;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('seleciona_ativarDesativar_'+i).checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Precisas de ir buscar esses `checkbox`, por exemplo com:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
```

e depois iterá-los mudando o `checked` para `false`.

Agora tens opções diferentes:

- Inverter o estado
- Forçar todos / nenhum

### Inverter o estado:

```
function marcarDesmarcarTodos() {
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        checkboxes[i].checked = !checkboxes[i].checked;
    }
}
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nwvgyd3d/

### Forçar todos / nenhum

Neste caso podes usar uma *flag* para guardar o estado. Também podia ser guardado no input num `data-estado`, mas no exemplo uso uma variável para isso.

```
var estado = false;
function marcarDesmarcarTodos() {
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        checkboxes[i].checked = !estado;
    }
    estado = !estado;
}
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nwvgyd3d/1/

Comment: Sergio ama querySelectorAll né? aheuhaeuhae fico admirado

Comment: @MaiconCarraro eu decidí à uns tempos não usar mais o IE8, e o qsa é para me ajudar a lembrar a decisão :)

Answer (score 0):

Procure pela função `each` do JS, usando jQuery...

Seu uso é bem simples:

```js
$("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
     this.checked = false;
});
```

[Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/pn9k7d3n/)

Answer (score 0):

Voce pode usar essa funcao `JS`:

```js
function marcarDesmarcar(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('foo');
  for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" onClick="marcarDesmarcar(this)" /> Marcar e Desmarcar todos<br/>
  
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar1"> check 1<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar2"> check 2<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar3"> check 3<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar4"> check 4<br/>
```